# Why sometimes when I paste a command on my bash prompt it gets executed even if I don't press Enter?

Tags: bash, copy-paste

The command get executed without the need of pressing Enter.
This can be dangerous sometimes...

Why is that and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you paste new line character with it. It's sometimes can be useful, for example, you can copy/paste many commands (long multi-line scripts) at once.

Well, It has never occurred to me to prevent this particular behavior. It's normal and expected. WYPIWYG - what you paste is what you get.

Comment: So if the new line character is at the end of the line, one work around would be copying all but the last character?

Answer (score 12):

When you paste into a terminal, it's generally treated just as if you had typed in whatever characters you're pasting. **The command running in your terminal can't distinguish between typed and pasted characters.** So if you paste a newline, bash doesn't know it wasn't *you* pressing enter.

If you can't avoid pasting the trailing newline, or if you're not sure if there even is a trailing newline, there are a options for making pasting into bash a bit safer:

### Comment before pasting

If you know you're pasting a single line, type `#` before pasting. That way, if there's a newline at the end, the command will be commented out, and you can then go back up and edit it.

**Note that if you paste in a multi-line string, this will only comment out the first line!**

### Use bash's edit-and-execute command feature

Safer, but a little more involved is to use bash's (seemingly little-known) *[edit-and-execute-command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-edit_002dand_002dexecute_002dcommand-_0028C_002dx-C_002de_0029)* feature.

To invoke it:

- if you use **emacs** keybindings (the default): `CTRL-x CTRL-e`
- if you use **vi** keybindings: `ESC v`

This will open a text editor containing your current command-line. You can set which editor is used for this with either the `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` environment variables.

You can then paste into this editor, and then edit the command(s) before they are executed. Once you save and quit the editor, the command(s) saved by the editor will be executed.

If you want to abort you can either comment out or delete all lines in the editor. Alternatively, some editors let you exit with a non-0 status, in which case bash will not execute the command. In vim, for example, you can use `:cq!` to exit with a non-0 status.

Answer (score 3):

A quick way to prevent execution is to type the comment character #, then paste the command.

I often do that because I fat-finger when copying and grab extraneous characters.

When you paste after the comment character, then the command is in the history buffer and you can edit it, uncomment it, and run it.

--- reply to comment

You're right, this only works for single-line commands. If you have a multi-line one in the clipboard, you can pipe the clipboard data through sed.

Stupid bash trick # 4 million and one:

`prompt:$ xclip -o -selection clipboard | sed --regexp-extended 's/^(.*)$/# \1;/'`

will turn this:

`for i in *.JPG;`

`do echo mv $i ${i/.JPG/.jpg};`

`done;`

into this:

`# for i in *.JPG;`

`# do echo mv $i ${i/.JPG/.jpg};`

`# done;`

Which is really not worth the effort, but kinda fun ;>

Comment: Great for single-line commands, but if it's a multi-line then the first instruction won't get executed, but the rest still will.